# DAX to lookup date in ValidFrom column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two (2) tables

**Tablename: X**

```
ID    Name       ValidFrom       Property
A-----Test1-----01.01.2010---------30
A-----Test1-----01.01.2015---------60
B-----Test1-----01.01.1900---------30
B-----Test2-----01.01.2018---------60
```

**Tablename: Y**

```
ID    Date
A---01.01.2010
A---01.02.2010
A---01.03.2015
A---01.04.2015
```

Ideally, I would like to add calculated columns to **Table Y** which looks up ID and date with ID and ValidFrom from **Table X**. In this example, row#1 in Table X would be the returning row of data for all dates >= 01.01.2010 and dates < 01.01.2015. The resulting outcome would be like this:

**Tablename: Y** (new)

```
ID     Date        Name    Property
A---01.01.2010----Test1------30
A---01.02.2010----Test1------30
A---01.03.2015----Test1------60
A---01.04.2015----Test1------60
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how the `Name` column is generated, but here's how you can get the `Property` column once you have the `Name` column in table `Y`:

```
Property =
VAR LastValid =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( X[ValidFrom] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( X[ValidFrom] ),
            X[ValidFrom] <= EARLIER ( Y[Date] )
        )
    )
RETURN
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        X[Property],
        X[ID], Y[ID],
        X[Name], Y[Name],
        X[ValidFrom], LastValid
    )
```

The `LastValid` variable finds the latest date that is less than or equal to the date in the current row. Then you use that along with the `ID` and `Name` to look up the `Property` from table `X`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Y[Name] would need to be populated from the same row as "Property" is gathered from table X by only referencing the Y[ID] and Y[Date]

Comment: Then apply analogous logic to get the `Name` column first. It isn't clear from your example how to treat different names.

Comment: It does seem to work by disregarding the name. Thank you very much Alexis!

Answer (score 0):

Taking in the last formula and applying the LOOKUPVALUE to the ID and ValidFrom as you refers, I tried successfully the next approach:

Name = 
VAR LastValid =
    CALCULATE(MAX(X[ValidFrom]);
        FILTER (
            ALL(X[ValidFrom] );
            X[ValidFrom] <= EARLIER (Y[Date] )
        )
    )
RETURN
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        X[Name];
        X[ID]; Y[ID];
        X[ValidFrom]; LastValid
    )